# Crystal Report Suppression of sub-report line if equal to 1

Tags: crystal-reports, report

How can i suppress the sub-report line and not appear if output was only 1 line.

https://www.kb.blackbaud.com/articles/Article/38218

I followed the instruction in the article above but could not find a proper way of writing the formula that if output contains only 1 line, suppress output.

But when i try something like rownumber equals  1, it's not working.

Appreciate your inputs on this.

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a formula like this and place it on Page Header:

Count ({Table.Value})

Then when supressing you can find the count in report fields.